# Rails 3 return query results to bottom of form page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a simple select form. When a year is selected from the form I would like the results to be returned to the same page but below the form.  Can someone explain how to do this?  Here is the form page (index.html.erb)

```
<%= form_tag("lookup/show", :method => "get") do %>
    <%= label_tag(:q, "Pub Year :") %>
    <%= collection_select(:lookup, :pubyear, @pubyears, :pubyear, :pubyear) %>
    <%= submit_tag("Find") %>
<% end %>
```

Here is the show method from the Lookup controller

```
def show
    @lookuprows = Lookup.return_lookup_row(params[:lookup][pubyear])

    respond_to do |format|
       format.html
    end
end
```

Here is the show.html.erb page that the results currently go to

```
<tbody class="lkuptbody">
    <% @lookuprows.each do |lkup| %>
       <tr class="lkuprow">
         <td><input type="text" class="lkupcode" value=<%= lkup.codetype %> /></td>
         <td><input type="text" class="lkupdesc" value=<%= lkup.codedesc %> /></td>
         <td><input type="text" class="lkuprmks" value=<%= lkup.rermark %> /></td>
       </tr>
</tbody>
```

I understand that I will have to make a partial _show.html.erb, but how do I reference that from the form page (index.html.erb)?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the results to appear on the same page but below the form, then the form should send the results to the `index` action, not to the `show` action:

```
<%= form_tag("lookup", :method => "get") do %>
  <%= label_tag(:q, "Pub Year :") %>
  <%= collection_select(:lookup, :pubyear, @pubyears, :pubyear, :pubyear) %>
  <%= submit_tag("Find") %>
<% end %>
```

and in your LookupController:

```
def index
  @lookuprows = Lookup.return_lookup_row(params[:lookup][pubyear]) unless params[:lookup].nil?
  ...
end
```

Then just append the table HTML in your show page below the form (in index.html.erb) wrapped in an `if` block to filter out the case where `@lookuprows` is nil:

```
<% if @lookuprows %>
  <tbody class="lkuptbody">
    <% @lookuprows.each do |lkup| %>
      <tr class="lkuprow">
        <td><input type="text" class="lkupcode" value=<%= lkup.codetype %> /></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="lkupdesc" value=<%= lkup.codedesc %> /></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="lkuprmks" value=<%= lkup.rermark %> /></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
<% end %>
```

This will show the results in `@lookuprows` as a table if there are any, if not it will not show the table.

You may want to put that table HTML in a separate partial to clean up the view, but that is not essential to the problem you asked.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I appended the table to the form page and, when I try to access the form page to select a year, I am getting the error `"undefined method each for nil:NilClass"` from the line `<% @lookuprows.each do |lkup| %>`

Comment: Oh right, sorry `each` won't handle `nil`, so you need to wrap that loop in an `<% if @lookuprows.present? %> ... <% end %>` block. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Ok updated, see if that works for you. By the way you were missing an `<% end %>` in your show code to end the `each` block (after the closing `</tr>` tag), which I added in.

Comment: thank you thank you, that worked.  I do want to put that in a partial. So if I create a partial _index.html.erb and put that results table in there, do I put this in the index.html.erb page: **`<% if @lookuprows.present? %> <% render 'index' %> <% end %>`**  Also then, if I want all form action(create, update, delete) to stay on my index page, then my index method in Lookup controller might be pretty big.  Thanks for the help

Comment: You should probably call the partial something else which explains what it does, e.g. _lookuprows.html.erb. Then you can just put a `<% render @lookuprows %>` in the if conditional and it should work.

Comment: Regarding your second question, you can have forms for other actions (e.g. create, update, destroy) on your index page, there's no problem with that. Then you can redirect from each of these actions to the index page from those actions, so the user always stays on the same page. You can also use AJAX as @Anthony Alberto has suggested, but that will add extra complexity. I don't think AJAX is necessary for what you want to achieve.

Comment: this lookup form is accessed from a home page with tabs (using jquery-ui), for each tab i have a **`<li><%= link_to 'Lookups', '../lookup/index' %></li>`**, when you click on that tab, the lookup index page appears, but still from within the hdrs tabs, and footers of the home index page.  However, when I submit the lookup form (using the lookup/index action), I get taken specifically to that page (lookup/index.html.erb), losing my tabs, hdrs, footers that i had on my home index page. How can I have the form action results appear w/ scope of original layout? Thx! (out of char)

Comment: If that's what you want, then you probably need AJAX, as @Anthony Alberto suggested.

Answer (score 1):

You want to avoid reloading the page and put it under the form? Here's how to do it with ajax :

Index.html.erb.

```
<%= form_tag("lookup/show", :method => "get", :data => {:remote => true, :type => "html"}, :id => "lookup_form") do %>
  <%= collection_select(:lookup, :pubyear, @pubyears, :pubyear, :pubyear, id: 'lookup_show_select') %>
   <%# Add More fields here %>
  <%= submit_tag "Submit" %>
<% end %>
<div id='lookup_show_result'></div>
```

In app/assets/lookup.js.coffee. If you don't use coffeescript, it's easy to translate to JS, just ask.

```
$ ->
  $(document).on 'ajax:success', '#lookup_form', (evt, data) ->
    $('#lookup_show_result').html(data)
```

Controller unchanged, just process the request according to all parameters

This is a minimal untested version, tell me if you're stuck

On a side note, I'm starting to develop a gem that will extend UJS implementation of Rails with jQuery here to make standard update/delete etc easier with ajax:
[jQuery UJS extended](https://github.com/anthonyalberto/jquery-ujs-extended)

Comment: How about if I have two selects I want to pass to the controller? Also, we want to return these rows into input txt boxes for each row. Would all that be done within the success: part of the ajax call?  Thanks for the help...

Comment: If you have several selects, the form should be submitted via AJAX. I'll update the answer

Comment: I don't see your reasoning. Why would multiple selects necessitate AJAX?

Comment: First I was proposing to just implement an ajax query on a `change` listener on the collection_select. Then, OP said he wanted several select to choose from, so in this case, he needs to submit a form. AJAX is optional of course, from what I understood this was what he wanted to achieve, but I was wrong apparently (see other answer)

Comment: @AnthonyAlberto To do this as a form using ajax/jquery, would I use  **`$('#lookup_form').on("submit", function (evt){ $.ajax({ ... })`**?  Thanks  I am using Rails 3.2.2 and jquery rails gem 2.0.1